# Creating a list of a custom object from a list of generic "Object" gets ClassCastException

Tags: java, list, object

So I have code that looks like this:

```
public void success(List<Object> profiles, Response response) {

    List<MyCustomObject> list= new ArrayList<MyCustomObject>();

    for (Object profile : profiles) {
            list.add((MyCustomObject) profile);    // this line crashes                        
     }

  }
```

So I get a `ClassCastException` at line noted above.  Can I do this?

Here is what I am TRYING to do, my real code is a bit more complicated:

I have a `List` that contains two types of Objects.  So, I am using the `Object` to hold both.  Then, once I receive this list from the server,  I want to break the list into two lists of my Custom Object (For example, `List<MyCustomObject>` instead of `List<Object>`.  So I am doing the cast above in my `for` loop so I can store the incoming generic object into its specific type of object list.

Is there another way to do this?  Am I on the right track?

Comment: Use "instanceof" operator to determine which object type and route to the proper list.  Maybe this puts into light the validity of the design?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, how about declaring two list types, instead of casting, use some condition and then populate the appropriate list?

Comment: @SandeepChatterjee  That is exactly what I am trying to do, and doing.  But my execution is flawed.  But it looks like `instanceof` is what I needed in addition to casting.

Comment: Assuming the two types are related, create a `Profle` interface that both types implement. To the interface add an `enum` type to differentiate the two.  As an aside, I recommend not using the word "generic" so generically as it has a particular meaning in Java.  Calling a plain object `Object` is sufficient and unambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a safety check before the cast to prevent code from crashing.

```
    List<MyCustomObject> list= new ArrayList<MyCustomObject>();

    int index = 0;
    for (Object profile : profiles) {

        // Safety check before casting the object
        if (profile instanceof MyCustomObject) {
            list.add((MyCustomObject) profile);    // wont crash now
        } else {
            // other type of object. Handle it separately
        }                   
     }
```

Comment: While the code solved your immediate problem, it looks like you have a bigger design problem if you're passing around `Objects` and binning them using `instanceof`.  `interface` and `abstract class` are your friends :)

Comment: I agree with @Paul. You should think about your design.

Comment: Ok,well, I will mark this correct, because it does directly relate to my question about a crash and it fixed that.  But I don't think I will be able to use this because of my design issues.  I don't know enough about Java to implement it like @Paul said, so I am going to have to do something much more basic and isolated.  Possibly two `async` Network Calls to get get back two separate lists instead of one Network Call and a list of mixed `Object` types.

Comment: If you have the time, take a look at this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html  A little time spent learning some of Java's core concepts will save you a lot of time and trouble in the future.  Good luck!